# tensorflow 2.1 loading model when saved with `tf` format does not work

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

Check the code below to create and save model 
[Github Issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38923)
[Try the code here](https://github.com/SpikingNeuron/tfpy_warrior/blob/master/tf2_save_and_load_custom_model.ipynb)

```py
# import necessary modules
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as tk
print(tf.__version__)

# define a custom model
class MyModel(tk.Model):
    ...

# Define a simple sequential model
def create_model():
    a = tk.Input(shape=(32,))
    b = tk.layers.Dense(32)(a)
    model = MyModel(inputs=a, outputs=b)

    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
                metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


# create model
my_model = create_model()

# Display the model's architecture
my_model.summary()

# save model
my_model.save(filepath="./saved_model", save_format="tf")
```

Now I want to load back the weights from disk. When I use the code below I get the error.

```py
# load back model
my_model.load_weights(filepath="./saved_model")
```

This gives the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/files.py in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
    171         if swmr and swmr_support:
    172             flags |= h5f.ACC_SWMR_READ
--> 173         fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
    174     elif mode == 'r+':
    175         fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.open()

OSError: Unable to open file (file read failed: time = Tue Apr 28 15:30:40 2020
, filename = './saved_model', file descriptor = 57, errno = 21, error message = 'Is a directory', buf = 0x7fff093afd50, total read size = 8, bytes this sub-read = 8, bytes actually read = 18446744073709551615, offset = 0)
```

But then I debugged and found the TensorFlow library confuses itself in thinking that it is an `h5` file. So I modified the code as below and now it works. I also get to use my custom `MyModel`

Basically I added extra path i.e. `\\variables\\variables` so that it detects the folder as `tf` checkpoint. Can anyone suggest a better approach?

```py
my_model.load_weights(filepath="./saved_model/variables/variables")
print(my_model.__class__)
```

The other option is to use `tk.models.load(...)` as in the code below. But, the
problem is I lose my sub-classed model `MyModel`

```py
_loaded_my_model = tk.models.load_model("./saved_model")
print(_loaded_my_model.__class__)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to use `load_model` to load the model that was saved earlier using `model.save`. If you want to `save_weights` and then load the weights back then you can use `model.load_weights`.

So you need to comment out the last line and use `load_model` as shown below.

```
# model.load_weights(filepath="saved_model") #
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./saved_model')
```

Full code is [here](https://github.com/jvishnuvardhan/Stackoverflow_Questions/blob/master/saving_loading_model.ipynb).

Comment: I have updated the code as you can see the option you suggest does not work when I want to subclass model. I assume that providing extra method `my_model.load(filepath=..., load_format='tf')` which is in line with `my_model.save(filepath=..., save_format='tf')` with extra kwarg `load_format` if needed can be a solution that is consistent with `save()` api..